# insert a js variable into a json object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a valid json object called `list_to_book_for`:

```
{"fold1-key1":{"name":"Van Antwerpen"},"fold2-key2":{"name":"Delporte"},"fold3-key3":{"name":"Lallemand"}}
```

I would like to add the content of my variable in this object:

```
"fold1":
    {
        "name": "Too book for ",
        "items":
        {

        }
    },
```

I want to insert the variable into items, possible ?

Comment: Could you show an example of your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all of you for your help, **this is the solution** :

I declare a global variable on the top of the code :

```
    chaine_book_for = {};

    chaine_book_for = function()
    {
        var tmp;
        $.ajax(
        {
            method:'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            url:'ajax/liste_users.php',
                                                                                    success:function(retour_php)
    {
                                                                                                                chaine_book_for = retour_php;
                                                                                                                tmp = retour_php;
    }
});
return tmp;
}();
```

Important thing is to put **async:false**

I insert the content in the sub menu (json object) :

```
"fold1":
{
    "name": "Too book for ",
    "items": chaine_book_for,
    callback: function(key, options)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, of course

```
var x = 'your items';

var obj = { fold1: { name: "Too book for ", items: {} } };

obj.fold1.items = x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
var jsonObj = {"fold1": {
    "name": "Too book for ", 
    "items": {} 
}}; // or do JSON.parse on your original json
var items = {"fold1-key1":{"name":"Van Antwerpen"},"fold2-key2":{"name":"Delporte"},"fold3-key3":{"name":"Lallemand"}};

jsonObj.fold1.items = items;
var result = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
```

will return:

```
{"fold1":
    {"name":"Too book for ",
     "items":
         {"fold1-key1":{"name":"Van Antwerpen"},
          "fold2-key2":{"name":"Delporte"},
          "fold3-key3":{"name":"Lallemand"}
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply I obtained missing : property id

Comment: I'm not able to add your code, this is my code, can you please take a look ? http://jsfiddle.net/Cp6uZ/ thank you in advance.

Comment: A lot of missing code there. Can you make another example, only with a hard-coded json that you get via ajax, and I'll make it work with items?

Comment: Thank you for your help, this is what I get from AJAX :http://jsfiddle.net/5HPPw/ and this is the missing code : http://jsfiddle.net/U5Ys7/  If you need something else, don't hesitate to tell it to me.

Comment: Again, I can't run that code, because it depends on external files. The first link is good, I need your original json in the same format. Here is my original code with your new items json: http://jsfiddle.net/3xHt9/1/

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this is what you want to do:

```
for( var key in list_to_book_for ) {
  if( list_to_book_for.hasOwnProperty(key) ){
     obj.fold1.items[key] = list_to_book_for[key];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON object is still in raw JSON format like this:

```
list_to_book_for = '{"fold1-key1":{"name":"Van Antwerpen"},"fold2-key2":{"name":"Delporte"},"fold3-key3":{"name":"Lallemand"}}';
```

Then, you can parse the JSON to javascript with `JSON.parse()`:

```
"fold1": {
    "name": "To book for ",
    "items": JSON.parse(list_to_book_for)
},
```

Comment: Thank you Julien for your help.  I have this error message : SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: What is the content of what you are trying to parse? Can you check what it looks like? e.g. add `alert(JSON.stringify(list_to_book_for))`

Answer (score -1):

Try use eval and for this code work ok, please look

```
 <script>
var obj={"fold1-key1":{"name":"Van Antwerpen"},"fold2-key2":{"name":"Delporte"},"fold3-key3":{"name":"Lallemand"}};
var s='{"fold1": {"name": "Too book for ","items": { } }}';
eval('var u='+s);
for(x in u)
{
    obj[x]=u[x];
}
</script>
```